# What Makes Pieces with similar BPM Sound So Different?

Tags: composition, tempo

Ok, so I'm very novice as far as music theory is concerned, and I was wondering if someone could explain to me why pieces with lower tempos can sound faster or higher energy.

I need to know why on an objective, measurable basis.

I thought initially it could be the note, but the pieces I'm looking at the major key isn't that different.

I'm looking specifically at:

- Nocturn #20 in C Sharp Minor by Chpoin - BPM 164
- We Didn't Start the Fire by Billy Joel - BPM 145
- Do It by Jupiter - BPM 99

Despite the tempos descending in this list, the top piece sounds the slowest and lowest energy, and the bottom sounds the fastest and highest energy.

Why is this? Is there any objectively measurable way to know why this is?

Comment: I didn't know the third one, so I googled it. Admittedly I listened to only about 20 seconds before I was bored, but… you may be confusing 'loudness' with 'energy'. It's a really ploddy track, just with a lot of compression making it feel 'louder'.  …but, tbh, these pieces do not have "similar BPM" by quite a way.

Comment: Based on the text of the question, a more appropriate title *might* be: "How can a piece of music with a lower BPM sound faster than one with a higher BPM?"

Comment: You ask about _similar_ BPM then list three works with _different_ BPM ...and from three different styles! Also the nocturne BPM isn't even remotely correct, it's 2 or 3 times _less_.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps counting the 8ths notes in the Chopin nocturne as beat? The C# minor Nocturne is not 164 quarters per minute! With that logic the *Do it* song you named would be 198 bpm and the *We didn’t start the Fire* song even about 290 bpm!

So the Chopin *is* actually slower.

But why does the *Do it* song feel faster paced than the *We didn’t start the Fire* song?

The reason for this is groove and the weight of the beats. Both songs have a so called double time groove with the snare hitting on the second and the fourth beat, but if you listen to the kick you hear that *We didn’t start the Fire* places the kick on beat on 1 and 3 while *Do it* places the kick on each single beat. This means that while the first song is clearly faster we’ll rhythmically align ourselves to to these pair of beats: kick - snare, so we will feel the groove as four divisions per measure but as two divisions per measure, or rather as two strong divisions and two weak divisions. The "Do it" song on the other hand forces us to align ourselves to each single beat, so we will feel the groove twice as fast as if it were otherwise.

Also on the *Do it* song the mix accentuates the kick much more, which gives it a feeling of energy (also keep in mind the difference in age).

Answer (score 2):

Who told you the Chopin was 164 BPM?   Some online thing aimed at DJs?  It's got it wrong.

Listen to it.

Now listen to a metronome at 164.

https://metronome-online.com/164-bpm

Is there any relationship between the two? Well, yes there might be.  I'd believe 82, half of 164 as nearer to the mark.  It's getting detected in 'double time'.  Automatic speed detection is risky!

Answer (score 2):

> Nocturn #20 in C Sharp Minor by Chpoin - BPM 164

This BPM is totally wrong. BPM wasn't used back then. The tempo marking is *lento* which would be roughly 70 BPM. Tempo markings cover a wide range of tempos so we can't give an exact BPM for lento.

> We Didn't Start the Fire by Billy Joel - BPM 145

Let's assume that number is correct. I'm familiar with the song and the tempo is fairly fast.

> Do It by Jupiter - BPM 99

I listened to this on Youtube. A moderate tempo of 99 BPM seems correct.

So, I agree with you that these works all sound different.

But, I disagree with the idea that the BPM are all similar. BPM of 70, 99, and 145 - let's just say they each differ by about 35 BPM - are actually *very different tempos*. If you gave only these tempos, without the titles, I would say the *expectation* is for the three to feel quite differently.

IMO tempo changes of around 8+ BPM are enough to start changing the character of a piece of music. It depends on the particulars of each work, and the mood changes might not be drastic, but the feel can change with a fairly small tempo change.

Take something at a moderate tempo with a bit of energy but relaxed feel, drop it 8-12 BPM and it might feel like it's taking its time, perhaps with a bit of swagger, drop it 8-12 BPM more and it might start feeling lethargic, maybe a bit depressed. I'm just generalizing, but something like that can happen with a song when you start playing around with tempos.

> I need to know why on an objective, measurable basis.

There is no objective measure for this. I mean, BPM is the objective measure, but there is no objective measure for how you feel about particular tempos or any other musical element. Music is art, which is subjective.

Answer (score 0):

As a very broad answer, the reason some pieces "feel" or "sound" slower than others, despite being measured at a higher BPM, is due to a macro-level beat.

In the first piece (the Chopin nocturne), for example, your BPM listing is 164 but the actual tempo marking on the piece is "Lento - Quarter Note = 69". The BPM you identified, therefore, must be occurring twice per actual beat.